# Cumulative frequency plot

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics

I have the following data:

```
data = {{0, 0}, {20, 1.4}, {25, 9.8}, {30, 32.2}, {35, 38.2}, {40, 15.6}, {45, 2.7}, {50, 0.1}};
```

where the second coordinates are frequencies measured as percent of total (adding, therefore, to $100$). I would like to produce a cumulative frequency plot. What would be the neatest way to do so?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you're correct describing your data as frequencies. I'm assuming you're using this phrase in a statistical context, meaning counts and not a physical context (in Hertz). Given you have *cumulative* frequency I suppose it's the former, but then how can you have non-integer values?

Comment: I meant accumulative. I was looking for the answer you gave me below, thanks!

Comment: I didn't say "cumulative" was wrong. I just made a remark about the values not being integer. I now assume they are relative frequencies and that therefore there's no reason for the term 'Total' in my answer (it does no harm either).

Comment: I didn't get that they were relative frequencies, however seems that you're right about that!

Comment: There still remain questions of the meaning and interpretation of these data, Frederik. *E.g.*, does the appearance of `{{0,0}, {20,1.4}, ...}` mean that $1.4$% of the frequency lies within the interval $[0,20]$ or that $1.4$% lies *exactly* at $20$? Should the plot reflect the data accurately or--as suggested by the accepted answer--attempt to interpolate between the bin cutpoints? Evidently the interpolation must be monotonic, but should it necessarily be *linear* (as in the accepted answer)?

Comment: Whuber, the appearance tells that it lies within [15-20], the next data part lies withing [20-25] and so on. The question I have been given does not require me to deepen out the exact interpolation. Thus, though it shouldn't necessarily be linear it satisfies my need.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
ListLinePlot[{data[[All, 1]], Accumulate[#]/Total[#] &@data[[All, 2]]}\[Transpose]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: you probably meant `Accumulate...data[[All,2]]`?

Comment: @kguler yeah, will correct figure when I'm near mma. Thanks.

Comment: Terse style (in the FrontEnd): `ListLinePlot[{#, Accumulate@#/Tr@# &@#2}\[Transpose]] & @@ (data\[Transpose])`

Answer (score 2):

You can transform the data as follows, and then plot `transdata`,

```
transdata = Partition[Riffle[data[[All, 1]], Accumulate@data[[All, 2]]], 2]
```

Surely this is a neat way, but it remains to be seen if its the neatest.

Comment: Also `# ~Riffle~ Accumulate[#2] ~Partition~ 2 & @@ Transpose[data]`, though I would use `data[[All, 2]] = Accumulate @ data[[All, 2]]; data` :-)

Comment: also, `transdata = Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], Accumulate@data[[All, 2]]}]`

Comment: Yes. This one looks good in the FrontEnd: `{#, Accumulate@#2}\[Transpose] & @@ (data\[Transpose])`  (By the way the only reason I haven't voted for this answer is that I honestly don't understand the question.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have performed a somewhat aggressive edit of the question to reflect an interpretation suggested by the accepted answer.